# Error 500 while trying to send message using Direct Line API from Microsoft BotFramework

Tags: python, botframework, direct-line-botframework, botconnector

Not sure where my problem is.  I would use the Try It Out option in the docs page but there doesn't appear to be any way of providing a token/secret.

I keep getting an error 500 when trying to send a message from a Jupyter notebook to my bot.  Here's my code:

```
class DirectLineConversation:

"""A conversation with a bot via the Direct Line API."""

def __init__(self, direct_line_secret):
    self._direct_line_secret = direct_line_secret        
    self._base_url = 'https://directline.botframework.com/api'    
    self._initiate_conversation()

def _initiate_conversation(self):
    self._init_headers()
    requests.post("https://directline.botframework.com/api/tokens/conversation", headers=self._headers)
    r = requests.post("https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations", headers=self._headers)
    json_ = r.json()
    self.conversationId = json_['conversationId']
    self.token = json_['token']

def _init_headers(self):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    headers.update(self._get_authorization_pair())
    self._headers = headers

def _get_authorization_pair(self):
    value = ' '.join(['BotConnector', self._direct_line_secret])
    return {'Authorization': value}

def send_message(self, text):
    url = '/'.join([self._base_url, 'conversations', self.conversationId, 'messages'])
    print(url)
    return requests.post(url, headers=self._headers, json={'conversationId': self.conversationId,
                                                           'text': text})


convo = DirectLineConversation(_DIRECT_LINE_SECRET)
response = convo.send_message("Hello")

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())
```

According to the documentation, everything in the schema is optional so I assumed passing json={'text': text} would work just fine however I have also tried it with all other values being null and also with the conversationId as I have seen in several other SO answers.

Here is the output:

> https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations/3BpMMKssV6P/messages
>   500
>   {'message': 'failed to send message'}

Comment: Does it work for you manually (e.g. with Fiddler)? It works for me. Is there an error message on the bot developer page? Also, you don't seem to use the acquired token anywhere. (I think you should open an issue on GitHub about the Try It Out issue).